# Creating a .bashrc function to search through all files for a particular string

Tags: search, function, bash

I have a useful little command that searches through all files & subdirectories for a particular string:

```
find . -name "*" -exec grep -il "search term" {} \;
```

I'd like to turn this into a function that I can put in my .bashrc and call from my shell without needing to remember the whole thing, but I can't get it working. This is what I have so far:

```
function ff() { find . -name "*" -exec grep -il $@ \{\} \\\; }
```

Can anyone help? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alias ff='grep -irl'
```

does the same thing but is much simpler and stops unneeded process creation for every file.

Comment: Looks good to me :). Why I was using find in there is lost in the mists of time... - thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in Solaris which doesn't appear to have the recursive option for grep. Find is usually the way to go in that instance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do this:

```
function ff() { find . -name "*" -exec grep -il $@ {} ';'; }
```

But that's nonsensical, not only because of `grep -r` as Mike Arthur points out, but because the clause `-name "*"` has the exact same effect as nothing at all.  What I'd recommend if you're going to do things like this at all is:

```
function ff() { find . -type f -exec grep -il $@ {} ';'; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, you'd like the [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) utility. It is somewhat like the function you described and more powerful. It is available in Debian and Ubuntu repositories with the name "ack-grep".

Answer (score 1):

find -exec has a limited buffer, and is technically slower, than using xargs.

alias ff='find . | xargs grep -il'

will work better when you are searching a large number of files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $ ff ()  {      find . -name "*" -exec grep -il $@ {} \;; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/). It will help a lot if you're using source control.

```
ack -il <term>
    <=>
grep -ril <term> .
```